# getting jsfiddle working with javascript extension scripts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Not a direct js question, but since jsfiddle is so useful for SO communication I think its worth asking.

Is it possible to get jsfiddle running with library extensions - e.g. in this example with D3's translate.js?  I've tried loading the script into as an 'external resource' but jsfiddle doesn't like GitHub and as you can see my own  version fails.  Any suggestions?

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/UR783/1/)

HTML:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/trinary/d3-transform/master/src/d3-transform.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
// svg container
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 300);

// a rectangle
var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100).attr("height", 50)
    .style("fill", "purple");

// d3 extension for translation operations
var translate = d3.svg.transform().translate(200, 100);

rect.attr('transform', translate);
```

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/UR783/2/ Also, sometimes you may run into the problem because `raw.github.com` explicitly sends [`X-Content-type-options: no-sniff` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_response_headers) which prevents Chrome from reading those files as JS. Using [`rawgithub.com`](http://rawgithub.com/) will solve that problem.

Comment: The rectangle is supposed to translate to (200,100)

Comment: I am using Firefox which does not respect `X-Content-type-options: no-sniff` and, hence, it works for me.

Comment: Ah a browser issue! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[github has started using `X-Content-Type-Options: no-niff` header](https://github.com/blog/1482-heads-up-nosniff-header-support-coming-to-chrome-and-firefox) which prevents scripts from being recognized as `javascript` or `css`. This is so that people do not start using it as a platform to host the production version of their files.

For usage of files on `github`, consider using [rawgithub.com](http://rawgithub.com/) for JSFiddle, or copying the complete compiled file to plunker.

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UR783/3/) using *rawgithub.com*